# Removing nonexistent files from git

Tags: linux, git, symfony, unix, ubuntu

There is information that git status gives:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

"src/HomeBundle/Entity/\320Apartments.php"
"src/HomeBundle/Repository/\320ApartmentsRepository.php"
"src/HomeBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/\320Apartments.orm.yml"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I want to remove these files from my computer, because I created them accidentally

I try to perform:

```
git rm "src/HomeBundle/Entity/\320Apartments.php"
fatal: pathspec 'src/HomeBundle/Entity/\320Apartments.php' did not match any files

git rm '"src/HomeBundle/Entity/\320Apartments.php"'
fatal: pathspec '"src/HomeBundle/Entity/\320Apartments.php"' did not match any files

rm '"src/HomeBundle/Entity/\320Apartments.php"'
rm: cannot remove ‘"src/HomeBundle/Entity/\\320Apartments.php"’: No such file or directory

rm "src/HomeBundle/Entity/\320Apartments.php"
rm: cannot remove ‘src/HomeBundle/Entity/\\320Apartments.php’: No such file or directory

git rm '"src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php"'
fatal: pathspec '"src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php"' did not match any files

git rm "src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php"
fatal: pathspec 'src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php' did not match any files

rm '"src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php"'
rm: cannot remove ‘"src//HomeBundle//Entity//\\320Apartments.php"’: No such file or directory
```

Please help me to find and remove them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need double slash like in "src//..."

you are using linux terminal, so you might be using bash. Try autocomplete:

`rm src/H<tab><tab>`

- you write `rm src/H` then press tab twice, it will complete to "src/HomeBundle" then you add "/E" and press tab twice. This will help you autocomplete the path an escape chars if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much! Double quotes are simply shows by git shell. My wrong files were in /src/HomeBundle/Entity/. I removed them via mc.

Comment: @DmitriyUrazov, good `mc` helped. Notice that double quotes (`"`) are ok in a path, but double slash ("//") are not.

Answer (score 1):

You can run ’git clean -f’ to remove all untracked files from working directory. Add ’-d' option to remove directories as well. You can also use 'git clean -n' to check out what is going to be deleted ( so called 'dry run').

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rm file_name` command to remove files tracking.

Comment: Worth to say that files are not being tracked so this is not Git related. Although, git rm will do the job because git is very nice ;)

Comment: I've tried this approach too, 
git rm '"src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php"'
fatal: pathspec '"src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php"' did not match any files 
git rm "src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php"
fatal: pathspec 'src//HomeBundle//Entity//\320Apartments.php' did not match any files

Comment: Check your file paths they smell! Try specifying absolute path with proper slash, I mean backward on Windows and forward on Linux.

Comment: forward slash on linux and backslash on windows you mean.